# IIS 7.5 odata expand is null

Tags: api, odata

I have two servers, the servers are the same windows version.
When I do this call

```
https://10.197.68.32/portaleclientiapi/odata/v1/ticket('FINLU%235R000239')?$expand=attachments&$select=attachments
```

the reply is this

```
{
  "@odata.context":"https://10.197.68.32/mpssapi/odata/v1/$metadata#ticket(attachments)/$entity","attachments":[
]
}
```

but when I call the second server the answer is this

```
{
    "@odata.context":"https://10.197.68.33/portaleclientiapi/odata/v1/$metadata#ticket(attachments)/$entity"
}
```

the call is exactly the same, but change only the ip address
10.197.68.32 or 10.197.68.33
can someone tell me where is the problem?
Both server have the same published website, I tried to copy files from the running ok server to the running bad server
Thanks

Comment: http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#10-01-debug-webapi-source can you try this to see the problem is occur in OData or IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put [EnableQuery] on the action or put [AutoExpand] on the property Attachment in the model